# Передача массива из функции

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

Бинарный файл составляю из 2 source-файлов, в одном основной код, в другой функции генерации ssl-сертификата.
Функция формирования сертификата (дополнительные функции не привожу) из второго файла.

```
int create_cert(unsigned char *buf, int *len) {
 BIO *bio_err;
 X509 *x509=NULL;
 EVP_PKEY *pkey=NULL;
 unsigned char *p;
 int i;

 CRYPTO_mem_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);
 bio_err=BIO_new_fp(stderr,BIO_NOCLOSE);
 mkcert(&x509,&pkey,2048,0,1490);

 *len=i2d_X509(x509,NULL);
 buf=malloc(*len);
 if (buf==NULL) return -1;
 p=buf;
 i2d_X509(x509,&p);

 X509_free(x509);
 EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
  ENGINE_cleanup();
 #endif
 CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
 CRYPTO_mem_leaks(bio_err);
 BIO_free(bio_err);

 return 1;
}
```

Тут я генерирую сертификат средствами openssl, с помощью i2d_X509 перевожу в DER-формат и записываю в память под указателем buf (а так же размер массива сертификата), который должен возвратиться туда где я вызываю эту функцию (т.е. в основной файл).

А вот главная функция первого файла.

```
int main(void) {
 char Cert;
 unsigned char *cbCertificate;
 int certLen;

 create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);
}
```

Тут я принимаю указатель и размер массива сертификата с предыдущей функции. Все никак не могу понять как можно взять массив из памяти и присвоить его в переменную Cert, чтобы после передать другой функции.
Я попытался записать сертификат в файл с помощью

```
  FILE *fp=fopen("cert.cer","w");
  if (fp!=NULL) {
   fwrite(&cbCertificate,1,certLen,fp);
   fclose(fp);
  }
```

Записывается всякая хрень. Я понимаю что cbCertificate это указатель на указатель. Я понимаю как можно взять адрес указателя, но вот к данным получить доступ не понимаю как.

Comment: int create_cert(unsigned char **buf, int *len) а так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас поняла, и Вы хотите вернуть из внутренней функции наружу выделенный внутри нее массив, используя в качестве параметра этой функции двойной указатель, то, для начала, нужно описать в параметрах этой функции **двойной указатель**:

```
int create_cert(unsigned char **buf, int *len){...}
```

Далее, выделять память под массив Вам нужно с учетом, что вы используете двойной указатель (Вы аналогично уже работаете с *len*):

```
*buf = (unsigned char *)malloc(*len);
```

Тогда, после вывова функции *create_cert()* в *cbCertificate* будет лежать указатель на новый, выделенный внутри *create_cert()* массив.

> Все никак не могу понять как можно взять массив из памяти и присвоить
>   его в переменную Cert

Так, как у Вас описано, это точно не получится, так как переменная *Cert* у вас имеет тип char, - т.е. 1 элемент. Нельзя одному элементу типа char присвоить весь массив.

Если же Вы, после того, как получили с помощью функции *create_cert()* данные, хотите записать их в файл, то запись будет выглядеть вот так :

```
fwrite(cbCertificate,1,certLen,fp);
```

так как

```
unsigned char *cbCertificate;
```

это не двойной, а обычный указатель. Вот когда вы берете его адрес, как здесь :

```
create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);
```

внутри функции *create_cert()* получается двойной указатель.

**UPD:**
Как выглядят двойные указатели:

Объявление :

```
int **cbCertificate;
```

Тогда инициализация такого указателя может выглядеть вот так :

```
int a = 0;
int *ptr = &a;
int **cbCertificate = &ptr;
```

И передавать такой двойной указатель в функцию можно будет вот так :

```
void foo(int ** pptr){...}
...
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  int *ptr = &a;
  int **cbCertificate = &ptr;

  foo(cbCertificate);
}
```

Если же двойной указатель нам нужен только для того, чтобы вернуть из функции адрес выделенного внутри этой функции буффера, то можно обойтись использованием двойного указателя только на стеке функции, тогда вышеприведенный пример можно записать так :

```
void foo(int ** pptr){...}
...
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  int *ptr = &a;

  foo(&ptr);
}
```

Двойной указатель является не чем иным, как адресом некоторого указателя, следовательно, работать с самим указателем и данными внутри функции foo() можно следующим образом:

```
void foo(int **pptr){
  ...
  *pptr = NULL; // инициализация указателя, адрес котрого хранится в pptr
  //(pptr все еще хранит значение, указывающее на некоторую ячейку памяти,
  //а вот эта самая память уже никуда не указывает)
  *pptr = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int)); // ячейка, на которую указывает 
  // pptr, указывает на массив из 10 значений типа int

  (*pptr)[0] = 5; // инициализируем первый элемент выделенного массива
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Над понимаем буду еще работать.

Comment: ну Вы уточните, что конкретно непонятно

Comment: Моего понимания работы с указателями. Вы объяснили все хорошо, но в будущем возможно опять будут у меня вопросы)

Comment: Ну если будут - задавайте. Сейчас приведу еще несколько примерчиков работы с двойными указателями.

Comment: @nerik, обновила ответ

Answer (score 1):

если грубо, то вы передаёте в `fwrite()` адрес начала блока данных, и, начиная с этого адреса, вы вычитываете 1*certLen байт (точнее читаются, а потом пишутся в файл, но не суть).

```
unsigned char *cbCertificate;
```

вы уже объявли переменную как указатель. Т.е. после:

```
create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);
```

значение `cbCertificate` - адрес начала блока памяти, где лежат какие-то данные (сертификат в вашем случае). В общем случае - это просто число.

Когда вы делаете так:

```
&cbCertificate
```

вы получаете новый адрес - адрес переменной в которой хранится значение (число) адреса вашего буфера.

Естественно, что когда вы передаёте его в таком виде в `fwrite()`, то вы передаёте не адрес начала буффера данных, а адрес переменной где хранится этот самый буффер. Размер адреса 4 или 8 байт или... зависит от архитектуры - 4 - 32бит, 8 - 64бит (не догма!). Т.е. тот мусор, который вы записали состоит или 4 или 8 первых байт - адреса буффера с данными, а потом просто что-то, что просто лежит в памяти за этой переменной.

Т.е. в вашем случае должно быть просто:

```
fwrite(cbCertificate, 1, certLen, fp);
```

если, конечно, вы ничего не напутали в `create_cert()` :-)

UPD: хотя ошибка в `create_cert()` есть тоже. Вы хотите из него получить адрес указателя и его размер. Т.е. вам нужно модифицировать переменную, которая хранит значение адреса. Таким образом, в create_cert() нужно передавать указатель на указатель:

```
int create_cert(unsigned char **buf, int *len)
```

Тогда аллоцировать память нужно так:

```
*buf = malloc(*len);
if (*buf == NULL) return -1;
p = *buf;
```

А вот вызов такой и останется:

```
create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);
```

А вообще, рекомендую включить предупреждения компилятора, типа `-Wall -Wextra` для GCC. Они много подобных нюансов ловят и дают предупреждения (отсюда и правило: хороший код - без ворнингов).

Comment: Программа заработала, спасибо. Ответ margosh первым помог.

Comment: Я не претендую :)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа некорректна. Функция `create_cert` объявлена, как имеющаяя первый параметр с типом `unsigned char *`:

```
int create_cert(unsigned char *buf, int *len);
```

Вы же вызываете ее, передавая аргумент, имеющий тип `unsigned char **`:

```
unsigned char *cbCertificate;
//...
create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение

Функция следует объявлена как

```
int create_cert(unsigned char **buf, int *len);
```

и функции выделять память для `buf` как

```
*buf = malloc( *len );
```

Также вызывает большие сомнения предложения

```
p=buf;
i2d_X509(x509,&p);
```

в этой функции.

Что касается вашего вопроса

> Все никак не могу понять как можно взять массив из памяти и присвоить
>   его в переменную Cert

то переменная `Cert` у вас объявлена, как имеющая тип `char`

```
int main(void) {
 char Cert;
//...
```

вы не можете присвоить ей массив. И более того массивы не имеют оператора присваивания.

Либо вы объявляете эту переменную как указатель `char *` и присваиваете ей адрес первого элемента массива, с которым собираетесь иметь дело. Либо выделяете память, равную памяти, занимаемой массивом, с помощью функции `malloc` И копируете туда массив, например, с помощью функции `memcpy`

Comment: Мне приходится делать unsigned char *cbCertificate, т.к. я незнаю размер массива сертификата.
Строки p=buf; i2d_X509(x509,&p); взяты из примера https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/d2i_X509.html

Comment: @nerik Я не смотрел пример, но в любом случае у вас тип аргумента не соответствует типу параметра функции. Если вы хотите, чтобы этот указатель после вызова адресовал выделенный в функции массив, то вы должны его передавать по ссылке, то есть через указатель на указатель.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow там целая серия проблем. но, по крайней мере вызов i2d_X509() - правильный :) он модифицирует указатель. Собственно правильно передавать не исходный даже указатель, а вспомогательный, типа p в этом случае.

Comment: @MonahTuk Я не вижу смысла в этом вызове, так как изменяется лишь локальная переменная, p, а не buf.  Может быть он корректен, но выглядит нелогично.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow не, ну если бы было правильно: p = *buf и соответствующим кодом в сигнатуре и просто выше, то было бы всё ок. Как раз не нужно модифицировать _исходный_ адрес, дабы потом было по чему чистить память. А новое значение, которое вернётся - это:
> If out is not NULL is writes the DER encoded data to the buffer at *out, and increments it to point after the data just written.
т.е. блок может быть больше, чем туда записалось, если вдруг хочется в свободное место что-то дозаписать - у тебя сразу указатель на нужную позицию. Плюс: p - *buf будет, по сути размером записанных данных.

Comment: @MonahTuk без этого программа вылетает в SegFault после завершения. Это рекомендация от разработчиков Openssl https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/d2i_X509.html

Comment: @nerik я про это же и говорю :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы с OpenSSL работали? смотрите, допустим у нас всё правильно с buf (это unsigned char** и аллоцировано правильно). Теперь мы "оптимизируем" и убираем "ненужную" p, вызов приобретает вид:  i2d_X509(x509, buf), а теперь, внимание, барабанная дробь, какое значение будет содержать cbCertificate, после всех вызовом? Правильно! то, которое модифицировал i2d_X509(). Т.е., допустим, выделили память, *buf у нас содержит адрес 0x12345678 и мы ожидаем получить этот адрес после возврата из create_cert, но после вызов i2d_X509(), там будет уже другое значение.

Comment: Пока коментировал, то, что коментировал удалили.

Answer (score 0):

```
int create_cert(unsigned char **buf, int *len) {
 BIO *bio_err;
 X509 *x509=NULL;
 EVP_PKEY *pkey=NULL;
 unsigned char *p;
 int i;

 CRYPTO_mem_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);
 bio_err=BIO_new_fp(stderr,BIO_NOCLOSE);
 mkcert(&x509,&pkey,2048,0,1490);

 *len=i2d_X509(x509,NULL);
 *buf=malloc(*len);
 if (*buf==NULL) return -1;
 p=*buf;
 i2d_X509(x509,&p);

 X509_free(x509);
 EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
  ENGINE_cleanup();
 #endif
 CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
 CRYPTO_mem_leaks(bio_err);
 BIO_free(bio_err);

 return 1;
}

int main(void) {
 char Cert;
 unsigned char *cbCertificate;
 int certLen;
 create_cert(&cbCertificate,&certLen);

  FILE *fp=fopen("cert.cer","w");
  if (fp!=NULL) {
   fwrite(cbCertificate,1,certLen,fp);
   fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Компилятор выдает:  warning: ‘cbCertificate’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized], а программа вылетает с Segmentation fault

Comment: Правильно вылетает. значение указателя cbCertificate не проинициализировано, содержит мусор. Блок выделяется внутри create_cert, но наружу никак не выползает. В результате значение cbCertificate в вашем случае такое же как было до вызова create_cert, а вот запись да, исправлена. Только толку :)

Comment: Пардон. Недосмотрел. Поправил. Остаётся вопрос что принимает i2d_X509.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/d2i_X509.html с ним всё верно.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов уже заработало, другие участники помогли разъяснить, но вам тоже спасибо за участие.